# Manage subscriptions on WSO2 API Manager without API Store Interface

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, swagger-2.0

I am using `WSO2 API Manager` to expose few APIs. But I don't want that the consumer use the API store for the subscriptions. The creation of `subscriptions/applications` and `Access tokens` should be managed through by my custom web application.
I have checked the WSO2 API Manager docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/ and imported the `swagger` in `SoapUI`. When I try to invoke the store api of my local API Manager I am getting the HTML content of API store page. see below screenshot.
[image]

Can anyone please help what I am doing wrong? Or is there any other way to the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass token which is generated by passing scope and client secret key and password as described in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#guide